# How Do I configure my setup in Visual Studio 2010 using Visual Studio installer to check for updates?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation

I have built an Application using visual studio 2010 and a setup using the Visual Studio installer. Now what I want is whenever the exe is installed on a client machine it should check for updates regularly.
Any Suggestions . Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's my experience that most people do this in the app itself, so that when it runs it checks your web site for updates.

Basically you need a web service call to which your app passes the ProductCode and Version of your setup, your MSI file build. At your web host you need a database (or Xml file) that has information on the latest available version and it's download location so that you can return that information to your app, assuming the latest version is higher than the running one.

You're in Visual Studio, so you build a RemovePreviousVersions updated MSI, and that's what you download and install. If the install needs admin rights and your app isn't elevated than you'd launch an external exe with an elevation manifest to get it installed.

Comment: That's what I needed .

Answer (score 0):

I just finished a project similar to this, but instead of using Visual Studio installer libraries, I created a windows service that runs on a 10 minute loop, and when the service detects a new version, it kills the running application and performs a download and copies the new files into the application folder.

There are a few things you need to take into consideration; 1) A way to gracefully warn and then close the application so the user is not angry over a forced kill of the application.  2) A web location to store the upgraded application files, and a web service to advertise the available application versions.  3) A way to queue the upgrades so that when a new version is released not every client will be upgraded at once (flooding your web server with upgrade requests and downloads).

This technique is used by Adobe for upgrading and installing applications such as Acrobat Reader and Flash.